# Calculate row differences in seconds of a datetime column with ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I have a point feature class in ArcGIS desktop. There is a timestamp column named `TS` in datetime format in the attribute table.

I need to calculate and write time differences of rows from previous rows to a new column named `RowDiff`. Results will be in "seconds". `RowDiff` datatype is short integer.

I've found these links but I have no idea about implementing the functions:
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-time/esritimedelta-class.htm
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime

I've found the following code but results are in string format like `0:00:06.00005` and useless for me. What I need is row differences in seconds and an integer data type, not decimals.

```
import arcpy

from arcpy import da

gpsdata = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)  

#set firstRow variable to true
firstRow = True

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(gpsdata, ["OBJECTID", "TS", "D_T"]) as cursor:

    for row in cursor:
        gap2 = row[1]

        #check if its the first row
        if firstRow == True:
            gap1 = gap2
            #set firstrow to false
            firstRow = False
            continue
        row[2] = str(gap2 - gap1)
        gap1 = gap2
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Sample results should be as follows:

[image: sapmle result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand that Esri didn't create the `datetime` object used to transmit this information -- This is a fundamental Python datatype. The Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) covers the `timedelta` that results from datetime subtraction.

The difference in seconds (`timedelta.total_seconds()`) is a `float` value because the `datetime` type supports milliseconds (though ArcPy doesn't use them), but you can cast (or round) to `int` if you want to.

Your code has more complexity than is necessary.  I'd do the following:

```
import arcpy

gpsdata = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)  

prev = None
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(gpsdata, ["OBJECTID", "TS", "D_T"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        tval = row[1]
        if (prev):
            row[2] = int((tval - prev).total_seconds())
        else:
            row[2] = None # could be zero
        cursor.updateRow(row)
        prev = tval
```

It might be wise to specify an `ORDER BY` so that your `TS` values are only increasing.
Note that you can change the correct *undefined* (`None`) value to zero if you want.